# css3 animation - fading

Tags: html, css, animation, webkit, dom-events

I'm playing with css3 animation / transition and I've noticed small issue in my project.

Source: http://jsfiddle.net/paranoida/cuwgQ/
Fullscreen version: http://jsfiddle.net/paranoida/cuwgQ/show

Requirement: Safari / Chrome

---

I want to create smooth fade between two slides. I used webkitAnimationEnd event to create callbacks.

Animation duration slides is set to **5s**.
Thumbs (progress bar) have their own duration (1s shorter then slides) = **4s**.

I added "current" class to next element if progress bar animation is completed. After that I removed "current" class from previous element if slide animation is completed. And so on...

It works fine between slide 1 and 2, 3 and 4, 5 and 6, etc. I dont know why js has problem with slides 2 and 3, 4 and 5 ;/
Maybe it's problem with synchronization but I am not 100% sure.

My concept:

1. [0s] start animation (first element has "current" class)
2. [4s] - next slide has "current" class
3. [5s] - remove "current" class from first slide
4. [9s] - next slide has "current" class
5. [10s] - remove "current" class from second slide
6. ...

It works fine in theory and for other class than "current".
Example: _http://jsfiddle.net/paranoida/cuwgQ/18/show/  
(You need to use webinspector or firebug)

Any idea?

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm following you, the problem is that some images fade to white, and you want everything to crossfade?

Comment: Yes, crossfade is that what I'm looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the animation-delay property to sync your animations rather than using javascript. It might be much smoother. Here is something I wrote that demos this: http://nimbu.in/unplugged/demos/slideshow.html

(also animations work in FF5 beta now).

Comment: Delay was my first thought when I saw this project :) But I cant use it because I will have functionalities like nextScene(), gotoScene(), prevScene(), etc. Delay doesn't provide me callbacks for methods.